# sas macro to count difference between two date strings & store the number in new variable

Tags: macros, sas-macro

Parameters `start_date`, `end_date` & `output_vars`. Dates are *charter string*. How can I convert it in a macro?

```
    data _null_;  
    start =;
    end = ;
    diff=end date-startdate;
    days = intck('day',start,end);
    weeks = intck('week',start,end);
    months = intck('month',start,end);
    year = intck('year',start,end);
    put  days= weeks= months= year=;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you have macro parameters then they will be macro variables and not data step variables. So you you need to reference the parameter value as &START_DATE, etc.
Second you can use the `%SYSFUNC()` macro function to call the `INTCK()` function in macro code.
Third you need to know the date format that will be used by the parameters. It is easiest if you just request that they use `DATE` format, then you can use the parameter values as date literals.

```
%let start_date=01JAN2015 ;
%let end_date=01JAN2016 ;
%let days = %sysfunc(intck(day,"&start_date"d,"&end_date"d));
```